# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in wp-content\themes\wppro\index.php on line 18

Tags: php, wordpress, syntax-error, wamp

before posting question here I googled couple of hours and as advised I turned on `short_open_tag` and `asp_tags` in my php.ini. I am using WAMP server and restarted it after configuring php.ini. But still showing that error. Can I help me finding what I missed? Here's what I have in my index.php.

```
    <?php get_header(); ?>

    <div class="container">
        <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
          <div class="span9">
            <section id="download-bootstrap">
              <div class="page-header">
        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
          <div class="page-header">
            <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
          </div>
            <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
            </section>
          </div>
    </div>

    <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not closing your `if` statement.

Replace:

```
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

with:

```
<?php
  endwhile;
  endif;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  Put this line after <?php the_excerpt(); ?>

  <?php endwhile; endif; ?>

  and also close container class div.
```